# area() plot covers plot axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I am creating a graph in MATLAB and then shading the background of the graph to highlight regions. An example of this is as follows:

```
clc; clear all;

hFig = figure;
y = [0:0.1:2*pi];
x = sin(y);
plot(y,x);
hold on
h(1) = area([0 (2*pi)/2], [1 1],-1);
set(h(1),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.8 0.6],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.8 0.6]);
h(2) = area([(2*pi)/2 2*pi], [1 1],-1);
set(h(2),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.5 0.5],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.5 0.5]);
axis tight

set(gca,'children',flipud(get(gca,'children')));

%# centimeters units
X = 14.0;                  %# paper size
Y = 12.0;                  %# paper size
xMargin = 1;               %# left/right margins from page borders
yMargin = 1;               %# bottom/top margins from page borders
xSize = X - 2*xMargin;     %# figure size on paper (widht & hieght)
ySize = Y - 2*yMargin;     %# figure size on paper (widht & hieght)

set(hFig, 'PaperUnits','centimeters')
set(hFig, 'PaperSize',[X Y])
set(hFig, 'PaperPosition',[xMargin yMargin xSize ySize])
set(hFig, 'PaperOrientation','portrait')

print('example','-dpdf','-r0');
```

In MATLAB the plot looks like this:
[image: MATLAB plot]

But the generated pdf file looks as follows:
[image: saved pdf]

Is there a command to force the axis lines back on top of the shaded areas as it is in the MATLAB plot?

Thanks

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on R2015b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was simple, just had to add

```
set(gca,'layer','top');
```

to force the axis ontop of the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the script (R2012b) also the in the "figure" the axis are masked by the two areas (and in the ".pdf" as well).

It seem the problem is related to the plotting rather than the conversion to ".pdf".

In particular the problem seems due to a coupling effect of the defined areas size and "axis tight" setting.

So I've sligthly reduced the areas size, replaced "axis tight" with the explicit defintion of "xlim" and "ylim".

Also, I've increased the axis "linewidth".

```
clc; clear all;

hFig = figure;
y = [0:0.1:2*pi];
x = sin(y);
plot(y,x);
hold on
% Modified area extend
% h(1) = area([0 (2*pi)/2], [1 1],-1);
h(1) = area([0.02 (2*pi)/2], [.99 .99],-.995);
set(h(1),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.8 0.6],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.8 0.6]);

% Modified area extend
% h(2) = area([(2*pi)/2 2*pi], [1 1],-1);
h(2) = area([(2*pi)/2 2*pi-.01], [.99 .99],-.995);
set(h(2),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.5 0.5],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.5 0.5]);

% Replaced "axis tight with explicit "xlim" and "ylim"
% axis tight
set(gca,'xlim',[0 2*pi],'ylim',[-1 1])
% Increased axis "linewidth" (notr strictly necessary
set(gca,'linewidth',1)
set(gca,'children',flipud(get(gca,'children')));

%# centimeters units
X = 14.0;                  %# paper size
Y = 12.0;                  %# paper size
xMargin = 1;               %# left/right margins from page borders
yMargin = 1;               %# bottom/top margins from page borders
xSize = X - 2*xMargin;     %# figure size on paper (widht & hieght)
ySize = Y - 2*yMargin;     %# figure size on paper (widht & hieght)

set(hFig, 'PaperUnits','centimeters')
set(hFig, 'PaperSize',[X Y])
set(hFig, 'PaperPosition',[xMargin yMargin xSize ySize])
set(hFig, 'PaperOrientation','portrait')

print('example','-dpdf','-r0');
```

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi il_raffa, thanks for your answer. I did not think to just change the boxes to be slightly less than the axis. That certainly works, but I I actually found the fix, i was just searching for the wrong terms previously.